# How to create (and verify) a hash with HmacSHA256 in deno?

Tags: typescript, hash, deno

I know how to do that in Python.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import os
import hashlib
import hmac
import base64

secretKey = bytes("passw@rd", 'UTF-8')
message = bytes(f'hello world\nhello deno', 'UTF-8')
encryptedKey = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(secretKey, message, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest())
print(encryptedKey)
```

[image: code output]

But I don't know how to do it in deno.
I would like the same result of the python code above in deno.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a HMAC-SHA256 hash with the help of the built-in crypto.subtle tools (available since mid of 2021) like shown below:

```
import { encode, decode } from "https://deno.land/std/encoding/base64.ts"

// just an example of the data for which we create an HMAC
const message = "hello world\nhello deno"

const encoder = new TextEncoder()

const secretKey = "passw@rd";
const keyBuf = encoder.encode(secretKey);

const key = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
  "raw",
  keyBuf,
  {name: "HMAC", hash: "SHA-256"},
  true,
  ["sign", "verify"],
)

const data = encoder.encode(message);
const result = await crypto.subtle.sign("HMAC", key , data.buffer);
console.log(encode(new Uint8Array(result)));
```

> kqfsOD/HMHBRL9F1Si4Y/qo9PCw2csuwXIGZK/P1IWc=

If the goal is to just verify an existing signature, you can pass the decoded signature to the `verify` function:

```
// validation of a received hmac-code
const hmacBase64 = "kqfsOD/HMHBRL9F1Si4Y/qo9PCw2csuwXIGZK/P1IWc=";

const hmacDecoded = decode(hmacBase64); // Base64 decoding

const verified = await crypto.subtle.verify("HMAC", key, hmacDecoded, data.buffer);
console.log("The signature is " + (verified? "": "in") + "valid");
```

> The signature is valid

---

Prior to the introduction of crypto.subtle in Deno there were two choices based on external packages:

You can use [God Crypto](https://deno.land/x/god_crypto@v1.4.8) for it, but that requires an extra Base64 module. Important notice: the owner of God Crypto stopped maintaining the package, therefore it's not recommended to use anymore.

```
import { hmac } from "https://deno.land/x/god_crypto@v1.4.10/mod.ts"
import * as base64 from "https://deno.land/x/base64@v0.2.1/mod.ts"

let secretKey = "passw@rd"
let message = "hello world\nhello deno"

const result: string = base64.fromUint8Array(hmac("sha256", secretKey, message))

console.log(result)
```

> kqfsOD/HMHBRL9F1Si4Y/qo9PCw2csuwXIGZK/P1IWc=

Or you can use the even more convinient [hmac](https://deno.land/x/hmac@v2.0.1) module, which has output encoding for "base64", "utf8" and "hex" integrated:

```
import { hmac } from "https://deno.land/x/hmac@v2.0.1/mod.ts";

let secretKey = "passw@rd"
let message = "hello world\nhello deno"

const result = hmac("sha256", secretKey , message , "utf8", "base64");
console.log(result)
```

> kqfsOD/HMHBRL9F1Si4Y/qo9PCw2csuwXIGZK/P1IWc=

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for an HMAC key in hex that is used to verify an interactive Slack request, using Deno.

Generic instructions to verify the HMAC signature for a Slack request can be found here: https://api.slack.com/authentication/verifying-requests-from-slack

```
import { createHmac } from "https://deno.land/std@0.166.0/node/crypto.ts";
import { config } from "https://deno.land/x/dotenv/mod.ts";

export const verifySlackRequest = async (event): Promise<boolean> => {
    try {
        const slackSigningSecret = config().SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET ||
            Deno.env.get("SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET");
        const timestamp = event.headers["X-Slack-Request-Timestamp"];
    // compare timestamp to current time to prevent replay attacks 
    // (if more than 5 minutes difference, reject request)
        if (Math.abs(Date.now() / 1000 - timestamp) > 60 * 5) {
            return false;
        }

        const requestBody = await event.body;
        const sigBasestring = `v0:${timestamp}:${requestBody}`;

        const mySignature = `v0=${createHmac("sha256", slackSigningSecret).update(sigBasestring).digest("hex")}`
        const slackSignature = event.headers["X-Slack-Signature"];
    // v0=b3d6055fd34da90b1174b678670d91fa0470da8b57c1a6ef82749cc9ec1ec6b3
        
    // it would be better to compare signatures using an HMAC utility, 
    // but I haven't found one for Deno.
        const isVerified = mySignature === slackSignature;
        return isVerified;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error:', JSON.stringify(error))
        return false;
    }
}
```